# writing a function of class which will build a string that holds all the information about the class object

Tags: python, list

i want to write a method of class and call it `dumpData` which will build a string that holds all the information about the object. i tried several codes but all i get is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dumpData'`

this is the code i have written so far:

```
class Car(): 

    def __init__(self, brand, productionYear) 
        self.brand = brand
        self.productionYear = productionYear

    def dumpData(self,CarList1):
             return CarList1

 if __name__ =="__main__":
    carObject = []
    for i in range(10):
         carObjectList = []

         brand_list = ['kia', 'Hunday', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Jeep']
         brand = random.choice(brand_list)

         productionYear = random.randint(1995, 2020)               
         carObject.append(Car(brand, productionYear))

         carObjectList.append(carObject)

  print(carObject.dumpData(carObjectList))
```

i edited this question because it didn't seem to be clear enough.
thank you in advance

Comment: According to your error, you cannot do `[some, data].dumpData()`. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: What you are calling a member function is called an instance method in Python.

Comment: `carObject` does not exist in your code... Even if this did work, `carObjectList` has no dumpData function, as mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Your error is saying you have a list object, not an instance of your class that you've tried to call your function on.

---

I suggest making your class actually hold the list, and the add function take the info you want

You don't need a parameter for the list, at that point.

```
class Car():
  def __init__(self, brand, year):
    self.brand = brand
    self.year = year

  def __repr__(self):
     return self.brand + "," + str(self.year)

class CarList():
  def __init__(self):
    self.cars = []

  def dump(self):
    return str(self.cars)

  def add(self, brand, year):
    self.cars.append(Car(brand, year))

carList1 = CarList()
carList1.add('honda', 2009)

print(carList1.dump())
```